How to connect to BigQuery using two service accounts in the same project?
I want to connect to BigQuery using two service accounts in the same project but accessing different datasets. I want to connect with airflow to BigQuery by using the BigQuery hook.
def connection_hook(ds_type,connection):
    if ds_type == "bigQuery_db" and connection=="A":
        hook_conn = var.bigquery_connection1
        hook = BigQueryHook(gcp_conn_id= hook_conn, location=var.bigquery_location, use_legacy_sql=False)
        hook.location = var.bigquery_location
    if ds_type == "bigQuery_db" and connection=="B":
        hook_conn = var.bigquery_connection2
        hook = BigQueryHook(gcp_conn_id= hook_conn, location=var.bigquery_location, use_legacy_sql=False)
        hook.location = var.bigquery_location
    return hook

I am trying to use this function but I don't know how to call the hook or close the connection.

Please check the airflow docs for bigquery hook for this. It contains all the necessary information on how to use the hook object (which is what your function is returning). Please try this once and in case you are facing any specific errors - then share the error here.
